# IE8 jQuery .text() returns empty string

Tags: jquery, text, internet-explorer-8, string

I have such strings in jQuery code:

```
$('#global-container').text();
$('#global-container aside').text();
```

All browsers, including IE8, return the same non-empty string for $('#global-container').text(), but:

for
`$('#global-container aside').text()` 
all browsers (but not IE8!!! why?) return non-empty string that contains many spaces and two numbers.
IE8 returns only empty string.
Why?

Comment: Could you post the other HTML code your using?

Comment: That's because IE 8 doesn't support HTML5, you can use this plugin http://www.code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: 'aside' is not supported in IE8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359895/what-are-the-most-likely-causes-of-javascript-errors-in-ie8
Have a look at this.Might help you.

Comment: Guys, thank you, I used html5shiv. Thank you for your solution. How to choose the best answer and close the question as solved, if you just commented my question? :)