# IE object required error from xml loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, parsing

I have a script which parses an xml document.

IE gives an error on this line.

```
alarmlog[j][0] = EALog[j].getElementsByTagName("LDsp")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I checked to make sure that the value is available. I can alert this value, and it looks good. But IE keeps showing the error

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.3; chromeframe/28.0.1500.95; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Mon, 19 Aug 2013 20:44:12 UTC


Message: Object required
Line: 503
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.254.105/sensorLog.html
```

Hoping to get some hints. Thanks

Comment: Can you alert `alarmlog[j][0]`? Assuming everything on the right side of the assignment operator is working an `undefined` value on `alarmlog[j]` could produce this error.

Comment: @JosiahRuddell Yes, I can alert alarmlog[j][0] and it shows the correct value.

Comment: My next guess would be data related. Possibly invalid characters or white-space. You would need to provide more information like an xml snippet and more of the code. Have a look at [common IE javascript mistakes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359895/what-are-the-most-likely-causes-of-javascript-errors-in-ie8) also.

Comment: @JosiahRuddell Yup you are right. I had more than one similar lines of code parsing the xml, and turns out one of them was blank, causing IE to break. Great advice. Not sure if you care about an accepted answers, but more than glad to accept it, if you can post your comment as the answer :) thanks very much.

Comment: Sure! glad that helped out. I posed the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you alert `alarmlog[j][0]`? Assuming everything on the right side of the assignment operator is working an undefined value on `alarmlog[j]` could produce this error.

**UPDATE:**

My next guess would be data related. Possibly invalid characters or white-space. You would need to provide more information like an xml snippet and more of the code. [Have a look at common IE javascript mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359895/what-are-the-most-likely-causes-of-javascript-errors-in-ie8) also.